# using URL parameters causes the page to jump to index

Tags: php, url, parameters

i have a PHP website , which heavily relies on URL parameters ( www.domain.com/page.php/?variable=value&anothervariable=value ) . It used to work just fine for 5 years , but yesterday my hosting provider did something and now whenerver my URL has any parameters , it causes the page to jump to index page ( but in command line , the required page is written ) . Clean URLs work just fine. I made no changes to the website.  I called the provider ( godaddy.com ) and they couldnt help . They said they moved my hosting to different server , so my IP changed , my hostname changed and my absolute path changed . I did update my hostname in SQL connection , so i have no problem connecting to my databases .

I did try to get rid of  .htacces and also tried to empty .htacces . None helped .

I spent almost 24 hours on the problem and cant get further . Really dont want to re-do whole website to clean URLs .... Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: the slash after the page is correct?

Comment: It's a shame we don't have any code to look at, maybe we could help you if we only had some code. Oh well... Hope you make it.

Comment: code example :  <li><a href="http://eurocatsuits.com/shipping-costs.php<?php echo "/?la=".$_GET["la"]."&currency=".$_GET["currency"]?>"><?php echo $popisky["kolik_postovne"] ;?></a></li>                         ........it did work before .....

Answer (score 0):

oh , so it took a while , but here is what was causing that :

originally , all links within the website were written as following :

www.domain.com/page.php/?variable=xyz

...and it worked for several years . After my hosting provider godaddy.com moved my website to different sever (not my decision and i found that out only ex-post ! )  , the links stopped working and they need to be without the last slash , that is :

www.domain.com/page.php?variable=xyz

...now everything works again . I am just being outraged at godaddy to change arbitrarily their server settings , which changes functionality of my website ... not the first time they have done that :-/